# Facebook Api: Create Post with image (PHP)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having troubles understanding the Facebook Api and hopefully someone can help me figuring out how to solve my problem.

What I need: Creating a Facebook Post on a FB Page with an attached Photo.

What I tried:

```
POST /v2.5/{page-id}/feed
```

-> I can only add the image as a link

I also tried using

```
POST /v2.5/{page-id}/photos
```

and then passed the returned ID to the object_attachment parameter on the previous (feed) API call. This seems to work but it does not look like the same when posting directly on Facebook.

I have an Link "facebook.com" under the Image and when clicking on it it opens the image in the user created Album instead of a Layer. (See attached image)[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf2hK.png)

Can someone please tell me how I should proceed to post a message with an image to Facebook so it looks like it was created on FB directly?

Comment: Are you trying to create a facebook share?!

Comment: I am trying to create a post to a FB page via the Graph API, not sharing a link